# Add step which results in a different value being passed in step definition

Tags: java, cucumber

I've the following step definition in my Cucumber test:

```
@When("Customer {string} connects, Negotiates, Sends DR")
public void customerConnectsNegotiatesSendsDR(String session) throws InterruptedException {
    buildsAndSendRequestToAgd(session);
    RequestMessage requestMessage=new RequestMessage("DataRequest","1");
    requestMessageBuilder.build(requestMessage).ifPresent(sender);
```

I want to update this so I can also have the step `@When("Customer {string} connects, Negotiates, Sends DR for snapshot only")`. In doing so, `RequestMessage("DataRequest","1")` would become `RequestMessage("DataRequest","0")`.

I know I could update the `@When("Customer {string} connects, Negotiates, Sends DR")` step to take a parameter of 0 or 1 but it would require I make the update in all feature files that use it. I'm wondering if there's a simpler way where I can default the value to one but if the step `@When("Customer {string} connects, Negotiates, Sends DR for snapshot only")` is used it opts for 0.

Is this possible or is there an accepted way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tried it but regular expressions are supported in step definitions: https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/step-definitions/#expressions, with the capture group being passed as an argument to the stepdef method, so perhaps something like the following would work:

```
@When("Customer {string} connects, Negotiates, Sends DR( for snapshot only)?")
public void customerConnectsNegotiatesSendsDR(String session, String snapshotOnly) throws InterruptedException {
    ...
}
```